# Grok pattern does not work for $ character

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, grok, logstash-grok

I use logstash to collect logs into elasticsearch. I'm creating grok filters for some logs by testing them on this link:

http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result

I have a problem with $ character. The bad thing is you cannot know if there will be a $ character inside the log or not.

An example log:

```
[8/11/15 10:34:47:047 EEST] 0000003b MbuRmmAdapter I   DCSV1032I: DCS Stack DefaultCoreGroup at Member TEST\G
```

The filter which successfully works for that log:

```
\[%{DATESTAMP:datestamp}\s(?<tzone>.*)\]\s(?<threadid>[\w]{8})\s%{WORD:logshortname}\s+(?<eventtype>[\w]{1})\s(?<msg>.*)
```

But if we put a $ inside MbuRmmAdapter word like that MbuRmm$Adapter, the debugger will say that the part after $ does not match with the filter.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the DATA pattern instead of the WORD pattern for your logshortname field and it should work just fine:

```
\[%{DATESTAMP:datestamp}\s(?<tzone>.*)\]\s(?<threadid>[\w]{8})\s%{DATA:logshortname}\s+(?<eventtype>[\w]{1})\s(?<msg>.*)
```

You can check out a definition of all the predefined grok patterns here:
https://github.com/elastic/logstash/tree/v1.4.2/patterns